# How do I just update my local git repo to the online repo?

Tags: git

I previously cloned an online git repo and would like to update it, but I am getting the following error. I have tried adding and removing the offending files, making edits...

I have also tried fast forwarding

```
git merge -ff-only
```

nothing seems to allow me to just pull the existing online repo. Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this

```
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Comment: Have you tried to rebase ?

Comment: I thought I did... I got a different response this time. I am not there yet, but it is progress. Thank you!  Is there no way to just drop everything and fast forward?  IAC, I will mark this as answered.